# Particular solution for $y''+y=\sin x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the particular solution $y_p$ for:

$$y''+y=\sin x$$

I set $y_p(x)=A\sin x + B\cos x$ and differentiate 2 times:
$$y_p'(x)=A\cos x - B\sin x$$
$$y_p''(x)=-A\sin x - B\cos x$$
I Insert into $$y_p''+y_p=\sin x$$

$$-A\sin x - B\cos x+ A\sin x + B\cos x=\sin x$$

And this cant be right, because the LHS. is $=0$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Thats because your $y_p$ is solution to the homogenous $y''+y=0$.

Comment: The method of undetermined coefficients demands that you add a factor $x$ in the resonance case (with multiplicity one), $y_p(x)=Ax\sin x+Bx\cos x.$

Comment: @Curl: In such cases you may take $y_p=Ax\sin x$ alone (if you are adventurous).

Comment: @LutzL Nice, this works.

Comment: @YadatiKiran  $ax \sin x$ wont work since when you differentiate you have terms in $cos (x)$

Comment: @Isham: That's why I said "if you are adventurous" (i.e. if you realise you can't if you have terms in $\cos x$).

Comment: I see @YadatiKiran

Answer (score 0):

When the RHS has the form
$$P_n(x)\sin(\omega x)$$

and
$(i\omega)$ is a root of the caracteristic equation, the particular solution of the equation $$y''+y=P_n(x)\sin(\omega x)$$

will be as
$$y_p=\color{red}{xQ_n(x)}\Bigl(A\cos(\omega x)+B\sin(\omega x)\Bigr)$$

$P_n$ and $Q_n$ are polynomial of degree $=n$.